# Request Response From Another Page

Tags: php, api

So what i need to do is send a GET request to another page which includes a key that will be used to authorize the user.

The Page is on a completely different website that i do not own. Its a api basically.

So what i will do is get form data on my site which reloads the page with `$authkey = $_POST["authkey"];` and then i want to send a request to `domain.com/?authkey=` and get back the responce with a if statement where if the responce = success it will show the page and if its fail itll show a fail message.

My only problem is i have no idea how to make this request to the external page and get a responce on my page.

How do i do this? Thank you.

Comment: Could you do it [with an AJAX call](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp)?

Comment: See [curl](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and/or [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another alternative is [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

```
<?php

$authkey = $_POST['authkey']
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/?authkey=' . $authkey);
echo $page;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Sending requests in PHP you can use the [CURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html), they provide some features to send requests in your PHP application. You can set some request parameters and request headers.
And in your example, You can send your "authkey" as a request parameter in CURL.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [guzzle library](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

**Example**

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/repos/guzzle/guzzle');
```